# Wordpress Plugin syntax error

Tags: wordpress, plugins, syntax

my Name is Julian. I 'm just in WordPress plugins to programming but stuck can anyone help me ? I 'm from Germany but my English is getting better ! :)

I have this code from a book what I bought , I hope you find a solution

```
<?php
/*
PLugin Name: Handbuch
Description: Einfaches Handbuch für den Admin-Bereich zum selbst befüllen
Author: Julian 
Version: 1.0
*/
add_action('admin_menu','handbuch_register');
function handbuch_register(){
    add_menu_page('Handbuch', 'Handbuch', 'edit_posts', 'handbuch', 'handbuch_ausgeben, plugins_url( 'handbuch/icon.png' ), 3);
    add_submenu_page('handbuch', 'Handbuch bearbeiten', 'Handbuch bearbeiten', 'manage_options', 'handbuch-bearbeiten', 'handbuch_bearbeiten');
}

functon handbuch_bearbeiten() {
?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Handbuch erstellen</h2>
        <form method="post" action=options.php">
            <?php settings_fields('handbuch_gruppe'); ?>
            <?php $options = get_option('handbuch_optionen'); ?>
            <textarea name="Handbuch_option[inhalt]" id="formularfeld" style="width:80%;height:250px"><?php echo $options['inhalt']; ?></textarea>
            <p> class="submit">
            <input type="submit" class="button_primary" value="<?php_e('Save Changes') ?>" />
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
<?php
}


function handbuch_ausgeben(){
?>
<div class="wrap"
    <h2>Handbuch</h2>
    <p>
    <?php
        $options = get_option('handbuch_optionen');
        echo $options['inhalt'];
    ?>
    </p>
</div>
<?php
}



add_action('admin_init', handbuch_init' );
function handbuch_init() {
    register_setting( 'handbuch_gruppe', 'handbuch_optionen', 'handbuch_validate' );
}
function handbuch_handbuch_validate($input) {
    return $input;
}
```

Comment: whats exactly your problem? btw you have a typo in `functon handbuch_bearbeiten() {`

Comment: Wordpress say Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'handbuch' (T_STRING) in //htdocs//wp-content/plugins/handbuch/handbuch.php on line 10
And Thanks i have seen That o :)

Answer (score 0):

your code is broken:

replace

```
add_menu_page('Handbuch', 'Handbuch', 'edit_posts', 'handbuch', 'handbuch_ausgeben, plugins_url( 'handbuch/icon.png' ), 3);
```

with

```
add_menu_page('Handbuch', 'Handbuch', 'edit_posts', 'handbuch', 'handbuch_ausgeben', plugins_url( 'handbuch/icon.png' ), 3);
```

you forgot a `'`

**update**
you have some of typos. here is another

```
add_action('admin_init', handbuch_init' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
/*
PLugin Name: Handbuch
Description: Einfaches Handbuch für den Admin-Bereich zum selbst befüllen
Author: Julian 
Version: 1.0
*/

if( ! class_exists( 'handbuch' ) ) {

    class handbuch {

        public function __construct() {
            add_action( 'admin_init', array( &$this, 'admin_init' ) );
            add_action( 'admin_menu', array( &$this, 'add_menu'   ) );
        }

        public function admin_init() {
            register_setting(
                'handbuch_gruppe',
                'handbuch_optionen',
                array( &$this, 'handbuch_validate' )
            );
        }

        public function add_menu() {
            add_menu_page(
                'Handbuch',
                'Handbuch',
                'manage_options',
                'handbuch',
                array( &$this, 'Handbuch_anzeigen' )
            );

            add_submenu_page(
                'handbuch',
                'Handbuch bearbeiten',
                'Handbuch bearbeiten',
                'manage_options',
                'handbuch-bearbeiten', 
                array( &$this, 'Handbuch_bearbeiten')
            );
        }

        public function Handbuch_anzeigen() {
            settings_fields('handbuch_gruppe');
            ?>
            <div class="wrap">
                <h2>Handbuch</h2>
                <p>
                    <?php $options = get_option('handbuch_optionen'); ?>
                    <?php echo $options['inhalt']; ?>
                </p>
            </div>
            <?php
        }

        public function Handbuch_bearbeiten() {
            settings_fields('handbuch_gruppe');
            ?>
            <div class="wrap">
                <h2>Handbuch erstellen</h2>
                <form method="post" action="options.php">
                    <?php $options = get_option('handbuch_optionen'); ?>
                    <textarea name="handbuch_optionen[inhalt]" id="formularfeld" style="width:80%;height:250px"><?php echo $options['inhalt']; ?></textarea>
                    <p class="submit">
                        <input type="submit" class="button_primary" value="<?php _e('Save Changes') ?>" />
                    </p>
                </form>
            </div>
            <?php
        }

        public function handbuch_validate( $input ) {
            return $input;
        }
    }

    $wp_bvgs_plugin = new handbuch();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much it does not quite work . When I press on the send button then brings me to option.php The book says the option.php done for rest

Comment: The function handbuch_validate()  is not executed but I don't know why :(

Comment: Ohh :( Okey I am very grateful to you !! I will now first continue to work with books and then try to write plugins for wordpress later :)